# Java 8 - Compare two collections

Tags: collections, nunit

I cannot figure out how to compare two same collections List in Java.
This should work, but it does not compile due to the void argument. Assert expects return value.

```
assertTrue(dateTimeCreated.stream().forEach(t -> dateTimeUpdated.stream().allMatch(u-> u.compareTo(t) >= 0)));
```

Can anybody help me how to specify comparison and use it with assert?
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to replace `forEach` by `allMatch`? Depends on what you actually want to test.

Comment: you are comparing entire list with single element `dateTimeUpdated.stream().allMatch(u-> u.compareTo(t) >= 0)`

Comment: I need to compare each element with another one in second list. I would like to avoid using for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
boolean allGreater = true;
for (int i = 0; i < dateTimeCreated.size(); i++)
    if (!(dateTimeCreated.get(i).compareTo(dateTimeUpdated.get(i)) <= 0))
        allGreater = false;
assertTrue(allGreater);
```

You can stream to count the index and check the condition then:

```
assertTrue(IntStream.range(0, dateTimeCreated.size())
                    .allMatch(i -> dateTimeCreated.get(i).compareTo(dateTimeUpdated.get(i)) <= 0));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted exactly. I think it is better to use stream rather than old for cycle approach, but I am not expert with Java 8 lambdas...

Comment: @Michal I have thought about the solution again and found that it is unnecessary to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` as `IntStream` also offers an `allMatch` method. Now it is indeed much shorter than the loop.

Answer (score 0):

since you are checking that if list contains same element which it does. You need to use other way one of them can be:

`list2.stream().filter(list1::contains).count() == list2.size()`

this will check weather you are getting return list have same elements that you are checking for

Comment: No, I need to compare actually two String elements between two list. I need to go through each of them and check if the value is equal/greater.

Comment: output is according to your question.

Comment: Yes, I did and both lists are equal. They have the same amount of elements.  I just want to compare A[0] with B[0], A[1] with B[1] etc... All elements in list A have to be greater or equal to elements in list B. That is my concern, how to do it via streams

Comment: I did the solution using the following code, but I would like to use stream:
for (int i = 0; i < dateTimeUpdated.size(); i++) {
   assertTrue(dateTimeUpdated.get(i).compareTo(dateTimeCreated.get(i)) >=0);
  }